# In Kafka, which __consumer_offsets partition the consumer commits the offsets on?

Tags: apache-kafka

The consumer should become in somehow producer for a specific partition in the topic `__consumer_offsets`.

What is the rule that links the `__consumer_offsets` partition to the consumer?

The consumer can actually consume from different brokers and not each of those brokers has the same `__consumer_offsets` partition.

Comment: Consumer API uses groupID, Topic, and PartitionID as a key to determine which partition of `__consumer_offsets` to write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kafka stores the information of a topic partition in an internal topic called  `__consumer_offsets`.

Request to read an offset is only served by the leader of a partition and committed offsets are stored on leader.

In-sync replicas also have to be in-sync with the leader partition.so they make the fetch request like from which offset they want to read data from the leader of the partition.

After reading from the leader partition, they also update the offset in their `_consumer_offsets` partition.

In case,the leader of the partition goes down.When the system comes live, any one of the in-sysc replica will be elected as leader and they have the latest committed offset.

So the assigned consumer to that partition will get the last consumed offset from the latest leader and start reading from that offset.

Hopes, It answers your question.

Comment: Sure! The behaviour is the same as for the producer. I was just overthinking. thanks